# can't switch off system after creating new user account

Tags: 12.10, users

I created a new user account, with user name and password.

Now, when I try to switch off my PC, from the top bar, it comes back to the login account screen.

When I click the relevant option, it suspends, logs off user and restarts, but does not switch off.

Any solution?

Comment: Can you at least do a `sudo poweroff`? Are you trying this from the new account that you just created?

Comment: No. I tried from the panel. But from the users I had at the time (myself -Administrator, the new user -Standard, and guest. All with same effect, taking me to the log in screen.

Comment: And does `sudo poweroff` work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you create the user? Command line useradd or the GUI?

If using the GUI, what type of user is it? Standard or Administrator?

Try to run the following command in a terminal:

```
id username
```

OR

```
groups username
```

You may need to add the user to adm and sudo group (`usermod -a -G adm username`) to be able to shutdown or reboot.

NOTE: If you want to understand why, check /etc/sudoers you see the following:

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Comment: I created the new user via GUI. System settings > User accounts.

Comment: Was that a standard or administrator account?